# Can I add Steam keys from Humble Bundles to Steam for Linux?

Tags: steam, linux, humble-bundle

[Steam for Linux](http://steamcommunity.com/games/221410/announcements/detail/1747660173332716773) is now in open beta, and the most recent [Humble Bundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/) (Humble Indie Bundle 7) is available for Linux, Mac and Windows. If I purchase the current Humble Bundle, am I able to redeem the Steam keys on Steam for Linux?

Will this allow me to download the Linux versions of these games through Steam, with Steam maintaining the games and keeping them up to date like normal?

Comment: Are the games listed separately per OS? I.e., Deus Ex Linux vs. Deus ex Windows? If steam only maintains a list of what games you own (and not which OS), it shouldn't care what OS you download to.

Comment: I haven't installed it yet, what with it going open beta today and my linux machine not being on - but for example, in the instances where I have Mac games in my library, they show in the library in Windows but when I try to install them I get a message stating "not available for this platform"

Comment: That would seem to reinforce the, "Steam doesn't care about the OS".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add the games to your account under Linux, but none of the games in Humble Bundle 7 [support the Steam on Linux beta](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8495-OKZC-0159) yet.